# How to release the sound in iOS when using SuperPowered library?

Tags: ios, swift, superpowered

We are using [SuperPowered](http://superpowered.com) library in our iOS app written in Swift and we encountered the problem that the sound is not released by the library and we can not find any way of fixing this.

The problem occurs when entering the view that instantiates the SuperPowered object and playing sound. This is the only place in the app that sound should be claimed. If the user is somewhere else in the app the sound should be released. The problem is that if we navigate to another place in the app and put our app in background and open another app like Spotify (that supports music in background), when switching back to our app the sound (from Spotify) will stop. The problem here is that SuperPowered library doesn't release the sound. Since our app is not a pure music app we do not want to stop other apps from playing sound while our app is in foreground (only when the user is in that view that is supposed to play sound as mentioned above).